# Middleware not working after deploying in vercel

Tags: next.js, vercel, headless

Hi i am using the headless cms 'next-wordpress-starter ' for my blog and added a middleware to handle the traffic coming from "x" site to be redirected back to that site. on local environment it works perfect but when i deployed in vercel it shows this error :
500: INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
Code: EDGE_FUNCTION_INVOCATION_FAILED

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';

export function middleware(req) {
  let referrer_path1 = req.referrer;
  console.log(referrer_path1);
  if (referrer_path1.includes('x-domain')) {
    let redirect_url = `https://x-domain/${req.nextUrl.pathname}`;
    return NextResponse.redirect(redirect_url);
  }
  return NextResponse.next();
}
```

is the issue from vercel side or is there any other solution to this kind of routing ?

Comment: What do the Vercel logs show?

Answer (score 0):

i too facing same issue, if you refresh the page you can see changes.

This is because middleware renders only once the page load again it stores within cache in production only.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35501274)